# CTE for Count the Binary Tree nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have the table structure like this :

```
Create table #table(advId int identity(1,1),name nvarchar(100),Mode nvarchar(5),ReferId int )

 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('King','L',0)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Fisher','L',1)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Manasa','R',1)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Deekshit','L',2)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Sujai','R',2)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Fedric','L',3)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Bruce','R',3)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('paul','L',4)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('walker','R',4)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Diesel','L',5)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Jas','R',5)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Edward','L',6)
 insert into #table(name,Mode,ReferId)values('Lara','R',6)

 select *from #table
```

How do to write the CTE for count the Binary tree nodes on level basis.
Here is the example,
[image]

now, what I want to do is if I'm going to calculate the Count of the downline nodes. Which means I want to calculate for '1' so the resultset which I'm expecting

```
count level mode
1     1      L
1     1      R
2     2      L
2     2      R
4     3      L
2     3      R
```

How do I achieve this, I have tried this

```
with cte (advId,ReferId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,ReferId,mode,0 as Level from #table where advid=1
 union all
 select a.advId,a.ReferId,a.mode ,Level+1 from #table   as a inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.referId
 )
 select *From cte order by Level
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have created stored procedure

```
declare @advId int,@L_advId int,@R_advId int,@level int,@L_count int ,@R_count int, @startId int, @EndId int;
set @advId=1;
with cte (advId,ReferId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,ReferId,mode,0 as Level from #table where advId=@advId
 union all
 select a.advId,a.ReferId,a.mode ,Level+1 from #table   as a inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.ReferId
 )
 select  distinct top 1 @EndId= Level from cte   order by Level desc;
 set @startId =0;
 while (@startId<@EndId)
 begin
with cte (advId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,mode,0 as Level from #table where advid=@advId
 union all
 select a.advId,a.mode ,b.Level+1 from #table as a 
        inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.referId
)
select @L_advId=[L],@R_advId=[R],@level=[Level] from(select advId,mode,[level] from cte )up pivot (sum(advId) for mode in([L],[R]))  cte  where level=1;
 with cte (advId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,mode,0 as Level from #table where advid=@L_advId
 union all
 select a.advId,a.mode ,b.Level+1 from #table as a 
        inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.referId
)
select @L_count=COUNT(*)  From cte where level=@startId ;

 with cte (advId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,mode,0 as Level from #table where advid=@R_advId
 union all
 select a.advId,a.mode ,b.Level+1 from #table as a 
        inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.referId
)
select @R_count=COUNT(*)  From cte where level=@startId ;
select @L_count as LCount ,@R_count as Rcount ,@startId as level

set @startId=@startId+1;

end
```

i have stored that data  into dummy table and i solved .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use aggregate SQL as a last statement (`Group by Lebvel,mode`):

```
with cte (advId,mode,Level)
as
(
 select advId,mode,0 as Level from table1 where advid=1
 union all
 select a.advId,a.mode ,b.Level+1 from table1 as a 
        inner join cte as b on b.advId=a.referId
)
select count(*),Level,mode From cte 
where Level<>0
group by level,mode
order by level,mode
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8511d/7)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you sir,but 1 have '4' nodes on his left and '2' nodes on his own Right which means (8,9,10,11) are left of 1 ,(12,13) are right of 1 at 3rd Level you can see at the demo

Comment: sorry, i just did some mistake in my Question now i updated my table records which is '5' have '2' nodes on his right,that's a mistake .i changed it .so please consider it again

Comment: Thank you sir, i have created stored Procedure and its worked. Thank you so much :)